# showing Error while running labelImg.py its display error

Tags: python-3.6

This was the error i am getting while running `labelImg.py` file

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.
```

And  I am running this code in ubuntu18.04

i tried export `display=0.0`
but still it showing same error